# Django extra-views: Is there any way to control how they are displayed?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want every form in a formset to be one bellow another and maybe to add some extra classes and display those images, but I don't have any idea how to do that. They are displayed like this:

[image: Picture of formset]

I have tried to do something like this in my template but there is an validation error occurring (MaganementForm is missing).

```
{% for formset in inlines %}
                {% for f in formset%}
                        {{f}}
                        <br>
                {% endfor %}
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add     `{{ formset.management_form }}` before the for loop this might help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates

Comment: Thank you very much, with {{ formset.management_form }} error is not happening anymore :)